# "403 Insufficient Permission" while creating a Kubernetes Cluster on Google Cloud instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, gcloud

I am getting some issues while creating a Kubernetes cluster on a Google Cloud instance.

I am running below command for creating a Kubernetes Cluster.

```bash
./cluster/kube-up.sh
```

Please see error below from the console:

```
Creating gs://kubernetes-staging-82aa46c1a5
Creating gs://kubernetes-staging-82aa46c1a5/...
AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient Permission
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the Instance has the necessary OAuth2 scopes (changing the scopes will require re-creating the Instance).

To run `./cluster/kube-up.sh`, you most likely need `compute` scope (to create other Instances) and `devstorage.full_control` or `devstorage.read_write` (to push Kubernetes binaries to Google Cloud Storage). To simplify, your Instance can just have `cloud-platform` scope, which includes access to all Google Cloud APIs.